getting error on sudo apt install mongodb-org -y
I am trying to install mongodb 7.0 version, I have followed all pre requisite commands, and installed all the dependencies. However getting error while executing "sudo apt install mongodb-org -y" command. please assist me with answer.
Output:-
root@test-vm-2:~# apt install mongodb-org -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@test-vm-2:~#
root@test-vm-2:~#

I have followed all pre requisite commands, and installed all the dependencies -- Please add details about everything you did regarding this

This question is similar to: How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
